# Simple php .. not working...hmm Looks very simple

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, xhtml

Please check the code below:

```
<?php
   $d=2;
   echo "the sum of the number is"."<sub>($d+1)</sub>";
?>
```

Its giving as output:

> `the sum of the number is <sub>(2+1)</sub>`

Ideally I need the output to be `"the sum of the number is <sub>3</sub>"`.
It works fine when we don't use the HTML tags `<sub>`...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try writing it as

```
<?php $d=2; echo "the sum of the number is"."<sub>".($d+1)."</sub>"; ?>
```

the quotes give it a string representation and thus not allowing you to perform addition.

Answer (score 3):

Move the expression outside the quotes:

```
<?php
   $d = 2;
   echo "the sum of the number is <sub>" . ($d+1) . "</sub>";
?>
```